# Preventing double call to brush reactive in shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, reactive, brush

I am using a brushed histogram to query samples in a shiny app. In my full application, I overlay a new histogram that highlights the selected region and update a DT data table showing properties of the filtered samples.

I've noticed that a reactive that depends on the brush gets called twice each time I move it. For example, the `table_data` reactive below gets called twice each time I brush the histogram.

`app.R`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
base_histogram <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    column(
      plotOutput("histogram", brush = brushOpts(direction = "x", id = "brush", delay=500, delayType = "debounce")),
      width = 6
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$histogram <- renderPlot({
        p <- base_histogram
        
        current <- table_data()
        if (nrow(current) > 0) {
            p <- p + geom_histogram(data = current, fill = "red", bins = 30)
        }

        p
    })
    
    table_data <- reactive({
        print("called")
        brushedPoints(df, input$brush)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this toy example, it's barely noticeable. But in my full app, a heavy calculation has to be done within the table_data reactive, and this the double call is unnecessarily slowing everything down.

Is there any way to structure the app so that the reactive only executes once whenever a brush is ended?

---

Here is a GIF that shows that the `table_data` is being executed twice per brush.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, only trigger once on each brush movement.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
base_histogram <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
    geom_histogram(bins = 30)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
    column(
        plotOutput("histogram", brush = brushOpts(direction = "x", id = "brush", delay=500, delayType = "debounce")),
        width = 6
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$histogram <- renderPlot({
        p <- base_histogram
        
        if(!is.null(table_data())) {
            p <- p + geom_histogram(data = table_data(), fill = "red", bins = 30)
        }
        p
    })
    
    table_data <- reactive({
        if(is.null(input$brush)) return()
        print("called")
        brushedPoints(df, input$brush)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This still doesn't quite seem to work. I've updated my question with an image showing the printed output when using the code from this answer.

Comment: worked in my browser. Maybe you are using a different browser or different system or you are too slow on selection. However, no matter how you are trying to fix the problem, I realize the biggest issue is Shiny doesn't have a `mouse-up` event listener. It means when you hold the mouse to select, the value of selection area keeps changing, instead of taking the final value when you release the mouse. This makes it impossible to fix with current version of Shiny unless you do custom javascript hacks.

Comment: You're right -- I had been viewing it in an rstudio window. In an ordinary browser, it doesn't call multiple times. The point about mouse-up makes sense; I'd need something more custom for that amount of control.